# Создание неизменяемых объектов и ссылки на них

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть некий код:

```
import copy

a = 'spamlkfna;inoianoiho'
b = copy.copy(a)

if a is b:
    print("yes")
```

В книге что я читаю выяснил, что тут происходит создание 2 переменных, которые будут ссылаться на разные объекты, однако строка if a is b возвращает True. Я не могу понять почему так происходит если is возвращает true только если 2 ссылки равны, то есть ссылаются на один и тот же объект. Это все проделки оптимизации? Или в версии после python 3.0 этот момент выглядит иначе? Моя версия на которой я работаю 3.7.1

Comment: Да, оптимизация. Если объект неизменяемый, то по сути нет смысла делать настоящую копию

Comment: Собственно, [вот тут в copy.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/0353b4eaaf451ad463ce7eb3074f6b62d332f401/Lib/copy.py#L105-L113) заполняется словарь `_copy_dispatch`, где для всех встроенных immutable-объектов прописывается копирующая функция, которая тупо возвращает тот же объект и всё

Comment: b = a[::] используя такую же запись результат никак не меняется

Comment: Это я уже не знаю как проверить, но наверно тоже оптимизация — видно ведь, что никаких изменений не производится

Comment: `b = a[:]` - это краткий и красивый аналог `copy.copy(a)`, основанный на том, что срез возвращает поверхностную копию данных. Для строки он так же вернёт ссылку на интернированный экземпляр, а вот для списка символов сработает.

Answer (score 0):

CPython [интернирует строки](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ec13b9322d95a651606219469fc7b7e9c977f248/Objects/codeobject.c#L49), поэтому вы не сможете сделать её копию. Но стоит учитывать, что это внутренняя особенность реализации и когда-нибудь это поведение может измениться.